# Change the icon of a jQuery UI button with own image

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, button, uibutton

Currently I have the following jQuery UI button:

```
$('#button').button(
  {
    label: 'Test',
    icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus', secondary: null}
  }
);
```

I wish to use own image for the button called 'custom.png'.

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Define a style yourself, like this:

```
.ui-icon-custom { background-image: url(images/custom.png); }
```

Then just use it when calling `.button()`, like this:

```
$('#button').button({
  label: 'Test',
  icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-custom', secondary: null}
});
```

This assumes that your custom icon is in the images folder beneath your CSS...the same place as the jQuery UI icon map typically is.  When the icon's created it gets a class like this: `class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom"`, and that `ui-icon` class looks like this (maybe a different image, depending on theme):

```
.ui-icon { 
  width: 16px; 
  height: 16px; 
  background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); 
}
```

So in your style you're just overriding that `background-image`, if needed change the width, height, etc.

Comment: changing the icon size more than 32 or so is non-trivial and, besides, there is one bug in 1.8.1 version : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5603

Answer (score 34):

Take a look at Nick Craver's comment. I tried his answer it exactly as is, but it still didn't help me. The issue (I assume) was that the `ui-icon-custom` class was at the end of the class list, and didn't seem to override it to original `ui-icon` class background image.

What I did to get it to work was add  !important to the end of the icon css like so

```
.ui-icon-custom { background-image: url(images/custom.png) !important; }
```

You might have to change the height and width properties, but this worked for me.

Comment: The last change did it for me too after fighting with it for hours.

Comment: Running into this again :) and this last change saved me hours of frustration.

Comment: Another way to have this work without using !important is to increase the specificity of the selector `.ui-state-default .ui-icon-custom` should work.

The reason this works is that in jquery.ui.theme.css, the selector is: `.ui-state-default .ui-icon`. By using only one class in your selector, your CSS will be less specific than the jQuery theme and it will not be applied.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You may also need to make sure your CSS file is loaded after jquery.ui.theme.css (According to the `<link />` tags in your HTML)

Comment: For reference, the definition in jquery.ui.theme.css is located [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css#L171) (That will probably change as the file is updated.)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm missing something in the OP, but this works for me without much problem. You can define the button as a DIV and put a table inside it. No overriding of css and you can still use both jquery defined icons and your own custom sized icon. You can also place the icon anywhere around the text (top, left, right, etc).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btn').button();
});
```

---

```
<div id='btn'>
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src='images/custom.png' width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td>Search</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, which gives one better control of button appearance while still taking advantage of jQuery UI .button() construct.

Comment: This answer is simple, straightforward and worked like a charm. Thanks so much.

Comment: this is so overkill, why don't you just use <button>? its much less work and much more neater than using bulky tables.

Comment: @php-jquery-programmer: any example to illustrate your idea?

Answer (score 1):

search  the jquery ui css file for the `ui-icon-circle-plus` class then copy it for your own image.

Answer (score 1):

If only an image to display at the button, without label or text, I do this :

```
$('#button').button();
```

to replace this image element to become a button :

```
<img src="images/custom.png" width="28" height="28" id="button">
```

But if you prefer following with label or text, tschlarm explanation above is better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2011/02/13/Creating-and-using-custom-icons-in-jQuery-Mobile

```css
.bouton-image { background: #004963; width: 80px; }
.ui-icon-wifi {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   background-color: #004963;
   background-image: url(../images/icones/icone_wifi_ispsm_mobile.png);
   background-position: 40% 40%;
}
```

```html
<a title="" class="bouton-image" data-role="button" data-icon="wifi" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a>
```

In "data-icon" just put whatever you want and jquery will create the class for you.

Answer (score -1):

easy or easy

```
#bildwechseln {
background-image: url('../images/my-png/bild.png');
width: 140px;
height: 140px;}

<button id="bildwechseln"></button>
```

Greetings from Germany