# How to make a custom-icon-only jQuery UI button widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, user-interface, ria

I'm trying my hand at jQuery UI as a replacement for other RIA techniques but I wanted to make an **icon-only** button. I'm aware that we can do it using the default theme-roller icons but I want to use **my own** icons.

I've successfully created (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224537/change-the-icon-of-a-jquery-ui-button-with-own-image)) a custom button with a custom icon *and* text, but if I remove the text then it becomes disproportionate and ugly.

I've tried just wrapping an `<img>` in a `<div>` and then calling `.button()` on it but it gets too large; what I really wanted is to have an icon-button like the ones that ship with the theme but using my own icons instead.

Hoping I've made myself clear and understandable,

FA

**(think extJS icon-only buttons or Adobe Flex (why have you forsaken me) icon-only buttons)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work for me (adapted from the demo [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons) and the answer you mentioned). It looks like the key is setting the `text` option to `false`:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#button').button({
    text: false, /* Don't include text on the button */
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-custom'
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#button > span.ui-icon-custom {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/25/25)
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ReKbf/

(Apologies for the terrible placeholder image)