# How to replace one icon in jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to use resize_handle.png image in lieu of the default resizable icon that came with the jquery-ui package. Is there a simple way of doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the icon of a jQuery UI button with own image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224537/change-the-icon-of-a-jquery-ui-button-with-own-image)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply override the `ui-icon-refresh` css class with a background image of your choosing.

```
.ui-icon-refresh {
    background-image: url(../images/icons/icons.png);
    background-position: -64px -80px;
}
```

There are also [styles for each type of state](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) (`ui-state-default`, `ui-state-hover`, etc). So you may need to override those as well.

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon-refresh,
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon-refresh {
    background-image: url(../images/icons/icons.png);
    background-position: -64px -80px;
}
```

Or, you can mark your custom css as important, which will override the more specific state styles defined by jQuery UI's css.

```
.ui-icon-refresh {
    background-image: url(../images/icons/icons.png) !important;
    background-position: -64px -80px !important;
}
```

Comment: Think I need to replace `ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se` or `ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se` class