# Use custom icons in jQuery buttons

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

I am very new in JQuery development and I have the following problem.

Into a JSP page I show the following JQuery **buttons**, in this way:

```
<button id="accept" name="ctrl" value="Accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton" onclick="sottometti(this,'<%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%>')">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>

<button id="cancel" name="ctrl" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton" onclick="sottometti(this,'<%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%>')">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
```

And at this time at these buttons are associated the standards JQuery icons, in this way:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".acceptButton").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-circle-check"
            },
            text: false
        });
        $(".cancelButton").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
            },
            text: false
        });
    })
```

Ok, my problem is that for these 2 buttons I have not to use the standard JQuery icons (**ui-icon-circle-check** and **ui-icon-closethick**) but 2 **png** icons named **button_accept.png** and **button_cancel.png** that are into a folder of my project.

How can I use these png instead the standard JQuery icons?

Comment: see this article : http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2011/02/13/creating-and-using-custom-icons-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: Try this stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224537/change-the-icon-of-a-jquery-ui-button-with-own-image